# Xamarin click handlers

Tags: xamarin

I've a problem with touch events in Xamarin IOS(on Android is ok). I've for example a ListView inside a StackLayout, and the ListView have no VerticalOptions FillAndExpand. If I add a TapGestureListener to the StackLayout, this intercept the event and the ListView ItemSelected event is not fired.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

```
async void onMenuListItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (clickNewPage || sender == null || (sender != null && ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem == null)) 
        return;
    clickNewPage = true;
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    //dowork
}

SLContent.GestureRecognizers.Clear();
SLContent.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
{
    NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
    Command = new Command(() => {
        if (menuIsShowed)
        {
            menuButtonClick();
            return;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: can you share some code (attaching the event, handling the event)?

Comment: sorry, I've edited the question and this is a piece of code